# Realm does something strange with Date

Tags: android, date, datetime, realm

I am showing date picker dialog in my android Application. After user select the date, I am saving it as a birthday in my user entity. I am using Realm Database. I don't know why, but everytime my saved birthday date in Realm is one day less.

Here is I am creating an entity to update birthday date. you can see what the date I pass.
[image: Nothing extraordinary]

And after that, I wanna get this updated entity with new birthday, but... surprise, It's not the same as I've passed.

[image: WTF]

Comment: You'll have to show some source code for us to work out what you're doing wrong.

Comment: I can't, you know, production code

Comment: Can you [create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? It’s surely a time zone issue.

Comment: I guess there is something wrong in your code because minutes and seconds do not match. As previously said, you must provide some code, we don't want to see your business logic or data, just classes declarations and how you save and get data